# How can I remove some elements from a list?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list with 10 items. Each item includes 3 items and I want to remove the 2nd item of each of the 10 items in my list. I would like to do it with a very large dataset. So I need a very efficient method. How can I do this ?

My training file is [here](https://gist.github.com/pachevalier/37f565fe8d66dc7c66b4).

Comment: You are active here long enough to know how a good question should look like. This isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple

```
test<-list(list(17413624, "item", 4167836), list(17413611, "item", 
    15284), list(17413151, "item", 11266439), list(17413068, 
    "item", 4663903), list(17413056, "item", 694589), list(17413006, 
    "item", 4167836), list(17412951, "item", 4167836), list(17412582, 
    "item", 1972868), list(17412061, "item", 4167836), list(17411835, 
    "item", 4167836))

removed <- lapply(test, `[`, -2)
```

would work just fine.